# MySQL - Count questionnaire answers.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

### Background Information

I have the following table structure:

```
Participants - id, email, organisation_type_id, job_role_id
Answers - id, participant_id, question_id, answer
Questions - id, question, question_category
```

There are two other tables, organisation types and job roles which just have an id and a name which are referred to in the above tables.

The tables hold data from when someone fills in a questionnaire (each question having a yes or no answer). Each of the questions also falls into one of two categories (denoted by the question_category field).

When someone completes the questionnaire, it creates a record in the `Participants` table and for each question it creates a record in the `answers` table.

### The Problem

I want to count the yes answers and the no answers for each question, but based on a particular organisation type (which is held in the `participants` table).

So for example, if I want to know how many people voted yes and how many votes no who are part of organisation type x, I'd want a query like:

```
Count all answers to each question, where the participant has a organisation_type_id of x, group by answer
```

To make it a little more confusing, I also want the row to be included even if there are no answers for that particular question yet. For example, I might have answers for question id x, but none from a participant who is part of organisation_type_id y. I'd want the question returned as a row, but with 0 in the 'answer count' column.

Is my table structure the problem here or is it just a really confusing query? So far I'm using the following query, and then looping over the results with PHP to check if it's part of the organisation or job role that I want, but ideally I'd like to do it all in MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM `questions`
JOIN `answers` ON `answers`.`question_id` = `questions`.`id`
JOIN `participants` ON `participants`.`id` = `answers`.`participant_id`
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT questions.id
  ,questions.question 
  ,count(answers.id) as totalAns
  ,Sum(Case When participants.id is not null Then 1 Else 0 End) as WithPart
  ,Sum(Case When answers.answer = 'Yes' Then 1 Else 0 End) as YesAns
  ,Sum(Case When answers.answer = 'No' Then 1 Else 0 End) as NoAns
FROM questions
left JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.id
left JOIN participants ON participants.id = answers.participant_id
                        and participants.organisation_type_id = 'x'
group by questions.id,questions.question
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want answer for questions and questions without answer you must select from question inner join answer. Below query give you questions with answer yes or no answer:

```
select p.id, a.answer
from Participants p
inner join Answers a ON p.id = a.participant_id
where a.answer = 'yes' or a.answer = null
```

Answer (score 0):

You want all questions. So select from questions. You want all answers to the question given by certain participants. So outer join the answers by these criteria. To get both counts (for yes and no) in one record sum them, rather than counting records.

```
select 
  q.id, 
  sum( case when a.answer = 'yes' then 1 ) as yes, 
  sum( case when a.answer = 'no' then 1 ) as no 
from questions q
left outer join answers a on a.question_id = q.question_id and a.participant_id in
(
  select p.id
  from participants p
  where p.organisation_type_id = 'x'
)
group by q.id
order by q.id;
```